# Intel 8086 Memory/Input-Output signal

Tags: memory, x86, intel, emu8086

What mechanism generates the M//IO signal of the 8086 microprocessor? If it is generated by the execution of the code, then what is the difference between it and any other address signal? If it is not generated by the execution of the code, then how the microprocessor "guesses" when there is need for either memory addresses or port addresses?

Comment: When [CPU 8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) performs instruction **IN** or **OUT**, it activates **M/IO** signal. This tells the supporting hardware that address pins AD0..AD15 identify the port number (device) and not memory address. It is the microcode of II/O instructions which activates the signal.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction "tells" the processor what kind of operation is needed, whether it is either a memory instruction, or an I/O instruction, for instance load and store instructions operate within the memory space, consequently these will activate the M//IO signal, while instructions for read and write (in and out) operate within the I/O so-called space, thus, these instruction deactivate the M//IO signal.